# Cypher Match-MERGE query fails on ConstraintValidationFailed

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints

I'm trying to create a `Node` with `Relation` using Match-Merge query with a `Unique Constraint` to avoid duplicate Node.

I have `Unique Constraint` on `C` label for property name:

```
| 11 | "c_name"        | "ONLINE" | 100.0             | "UNIQUE"    | "BTREE"    | "NODE"     | ["C"]   | ["name"]             | "native-btree-1.0" |
```

And I'm using this query:

```
MATCH (n:N)
where id(n)=10
MERGE (n)-[r:Relates]->(c:C {name: "Test", parts: ["Test"]})
```

The `N` Node always exists but Node `C` can be non-existent and I expect it to be created if so.

I get this error when `C` with duplicate `name` exists!

```
ConstraintValidationFailed: Node(373009) already exists with label `C` and property `name` = 'Test'
```

What is the problem? doesn't `Merge` query make the duplicate Node to be merged or skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entire pattern does not yet exist, [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) will attempt to create it.

So, either:

- `(c:C {name: "Test"})` already exists, but `c.parts` is not the same as `["Test"]` (or is missing), OR
- `(c:C {name: "Test", parts: ["Test"]})` already exists, but there is no `Relates` relationship to it from `n`.

In either case, `MERGE` will go ahead and try to create the pattern, resulting in a constraint violation.

This query would have avoided that situation:

```
MATCH (n:N)
WHERE ID(n) = 10
MERGE (c:C {name: "Test"})
ON CREATE SET c.parts = ["Test"]
MERGE (n)-[:Relates]->(c)
```